# How to Restore Git Repository

Tags: git, restore

My Git repository is on the server and I need to...

- restore the repository
- remove logs / history
- remove all files

How could I do it? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by restore? Do you mean you want to delete the logs, history and files from the server or from a local copy of the repo?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the logs, history and files from the server.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is possible (..that would enable everyone with access to a repo to destroy it). And I actually don't see the reason why you would want to do this. Just ask the provider of you git repo to reinitialize or create a fresh repo for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to `git push origin :<remote branch name>` for every single remote branch.  This will delete all remote branches and eventually the old object db will probably be cleaned up.

To do this in a bash one liner execute something like this: `for i in $(git branch -r | grep origin | sed 's#origin/##'); do git push origin :$i; done`.  I haven't tried this, nor do I want to.

Where exactly is this repo hosted that you don't have ssh access and can't delete it through some other method (github, et al should have some way of deleting them manually)?

Answer (score -1):

You could ssh into the server, go to the directory, make sure you are where you expect, and delete it with "rm -rf $path".

Comment: But I don't have access to the server, only to the Git repository.

Comment: make sure not to do the similar command `sudo rm -rf $PATH` :)